# mysql DATE_FORMAT() between gives me bug

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying folowing on my_table where modifiedtime is of type `datetime`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y') from my_table
where DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y') between '05-11-2013' and '28-11-2013';
```

The query gives me some other record too which are not falls between above dates, for example there is a record  in result set  dated `'04-01-2014'`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y') from my_table
    where DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y')='05-11-2013'
```

this query works fine and gives all the records for the given date

```
why the first behaves like that?
How can i correct it?
what is the efficient way to implement it?
```

such that i can get all the records only between given two dates.

Comment: Try this, `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM my_table WHERE modifiedtime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('05-11-2013', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('28-11-2013', '%d-%m-%Y');`

Comment: This one works for me

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    modifiedtime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('05-11-2013', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('28-11-2013', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same as in the question. In the question, `modifiedtime` was truncated before being compared.

Comment: I have used `STR_TO_DATE` instead of `DATE_FORMAT` in `WHERE` Clause.

Comment: Take for example the date `2013-11-28 14:00:00`. It will be inside the interval in the question(since it was truncated to `2013-11-28`, but outside the interval in your answer.

Comment: Although this _is_ the better way to form the query (as you're more likely to use indices), you [shouldn't use BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  This _does_ apply to MySQL, as timestamps can have differing fractional seconds.  Note that querying with an exclusive upper bound will fix the "truncation" issue as mentioned by @KlasLindbäck.

Answer (score 0):

DATE_FORMAT() returns TEXT type column and dates can't be applied.

Use without DATE_FORMAT in the WHERE

```
select DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y') from my_table
where modifiedtime between '05-11-2013' and '28-11-2013';
```

Comment: Don't you need to convert the limits from string to date (or at least provide them in a format that can be automatically converted to date).

Comment: it not works.Not gives any result, may be because the filed in datetime format

Answer (score 0):

you DATE_FORMAT function converts the column modifiedtime to String.
and hence in your first query you do a string comparison rather then a date comparison.
Also your date literal is not incorrect. It must be of form YYYY-MM-DD

```
select DATE_FORMAT(modifiedtime,'%d-%m-%Y') from my_table
where cast(modifiedtime as date) between '2013-11-05' and '2013-11-28';
```

Comment: Hopefully `modifiedTime` is already a date or timestamp, in which case the `CAST(...)` is not needed.  Also, [don't use BETWEEN with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  MySQL _can_ have different fractional seconds, so this does apply.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The cast is to make the column date a field instead of a timestamp. Because of the first point I believe the second is not applicable.

Comment: ...in that case you're (most likely) ignoring indices, and the query will take longer than necessary.  Personally,  believe that the use of `BETWEEN` should be avoided altogether, as it fosters an incorrect perception of ranges (namely, that there are discrete values).